# Assigning firestore data to custom object

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swift5

I am trying to make an app that uses Firestore to store customer specific specs. I have a spec object that only has a few properties for now, but I need to take the data and assign it to a new Spec object, which then will be appended to an array to display on a tableView. I don't understand how to access the individual maps in the array to assign the values to each property for the spec. I currently have it set to print in the console, as every time I try to assign a value from the document it is nil. Essentially I need to store data under customers(a total list of all the customers) and among other data have an array of specs that contain specNumber, specDescription, and palletCount for each customer.

example:

```
Customer: Test
Specs:
3096:
    Description: 50#top
    pltCount: 250
3097:
    Description: 50#bottom
    pltCount: 250
```

Firestore data:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qir1.png)

Code:

```
    let settings = FirestoreSettings()
    
    Firestore.firestore().settings = settings
    
    db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    
    db.collection("customers/test/specs")//.whereField("isCustomer", isEqualTo: true)
        .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
            if let err = err {
                print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
            } else {
                for document in querySnapshot!.documents {

                    print("\(document.documentID) => \(document.data())")
                    
                }
            }
    }
```

Spec calls code:

```
struct Spec {
    
    // Properties
    var specNumber: String
    var specDescription: String
    var palletCount: Int
    //var palletsOrdered = 0

    init(specNum: Int, specDesc: String, pltCount: Int) {

        specNumber = "\(specNum)"
        specDescription = specDesc
        palletCount = pltCount

    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must separate access to documents from access to data within documents (you attempt to do it together). You cannot call `getDocuments()` on a document or a field within a document, only on a collection. So instead of `db.collection("customers/test/specs").getDocuments()`, try:

```
db.collection("customers").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in ... }
```

Then to get data from the documents:

```
db.collection("customers").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in
    if let snapshot = snapshot { // lead by unwrapping the snapshot instead of the error
        for doc in snapshot.documents { // iterate through the documents
            guard let specs = doc.get("specs") as? [[String: Any]] else {
                continue // continue loop
            }
            for s in specs { // iterate through the array of specs
                if let specNum = s["SpecNum"] as? String,
                    let specDesc = s["SpecDesc"] as? String,
                    let pltCount = s["PalletCount"] as? Int {
                        let spec = Spec(specNum: specNum, specDesc: specDesc, pltCount: pltCount)
                        self.someArray.append(spec)
                    }
            }

            self.tableView.reloadData() // loop is done, reload
        }
    } else {
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

This is a very simplified version of how I imagine you'd actually want to implement it, depending on how the table/collection was reloaded (on the fly, routinely, or just once). Also, each document contains an array of specs but you're fetching all documents from the collection, which would give you a ton of specs without any indication of which spec is tied to which customer. But I suspect this is just early setup and you're just trying to get a handle on the API first.

Note: Maps in Firestore are called dictionaries in Swift and they always come back from Firestore as `[String: Any]` dictionaries. That's why when we originally unwrapped the specs map, we cast it as an array of dictionaries:

```
let specs = doc.get("specs") as? [[String: Any]]
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!! I have been stuck on this for awhile. Thank you for your explanation as well, it helps me a lot. I would think ideally I would call it once the app is open, as the customers specs will not change that often. Again thank you!

Comment: How would I account for different customers? So if I added another customer as test2, I cannot do db.collection("customers/test2").getDocuments() { (snapshot, error) in ... } to pull just their specs. I know further down the line it will not be hard coded, but a String variable based on which user logs in.

Comment: I know if I rename each array customerNameSpecs and have that be a variable that changes based on which user is logged in, it would then only pull their specs. I can then call.                                                                                                                 guard let specs = doc.get("customerNamespecs") as? [[String: Any]] else {
I am just wondering if their is a better way.

Comment: `db.document("customers/test2").getDocument() { snapshot error in ... }` is what you would do. It's hard to say how to architect your data without knowing much about it but I would imagine you'd want an individual document per customer, or an individual document per spec. Not only does Firestore work best with lots of small documents, each document has a size limit (collections don't). So if customers had tens or hundreds of specs, you'd be better off giving each spec its own document. To find all specs of a given user, query the collection where the `userId` field equaled the user's ID.

Comment: If I do that I get "Thread 1: Exception: "Invalid collection reference. Collection references must have an odd number of segments, but customers/test2 has 2". Based off what you said would it make more sense to have a collection as the spec number, and inside the fields be things like pallet scout and description? At max customers would only have 200 specs. I was thinking of filtering by userId, just trying to think of the best way to structure the data to contain that, thank you.

Comment: Make sure you're doing `db.document(...)` and not `db.collection(...)`. Each document can certainly hold 200 specs if they're about the size in the example. The best way to architect your data with NoSQL (which is what Firestore is) is to construct everything for the specific queries you want to make. First figure out what the queries will be (exactly what is the data that you will need) and then tailor your data architecture to those queries. And keep in mind that documents have size limits and Firestore charges per document read/write/edit.

Comment: First watch this video about NoSQL and get a good handle on the technology itself. DynamoDB and Firestore are both NoSQL databases and are very similar in certain areas so the concepts in the video will apply to Firestore. https://youtu.be/HaEPXoXVf2k

Comment: Perfect thank you! I think I understand, and thank you for the help. The active users will be relatively minimum. Thank you again for all your help.

Comment: Don't forget to accept and upvote the answer if it has answered your question.

Comment: Thank you for the reminder to do that, I did upvote it but I don't have reputation yet.